# Map two Collection of different type using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, collections, automapper

I have a DTO and an entity both called `QuestionnaireSubmission` mapper together like this :

```
public QuestionSubmissionMapper() => this.CreateMap<DTO.QuestionnaireSubmission, QuestionnaireSubmission>()
            .ForMember(d => d.ParticipantId, d => d.MapFrom(s => s.ParticipationId))
            .ForMember(d => d.SurveyVersionId, d => d.MapFrom(s => s.Survey.Version))
            .ForMember(d => d.RespondantAnswers, d => d.MapFrom(s => s.States));
```

My issue is that I can't figure out how to map `s.States of type State[]` and `RespondantAnswers of type IEnumerable<RespondantAnswer>`

I have already created a map between these two classes to map them.

```
 this.CreateMap<State, RespondantAnswer>()
                .ForMember(d => d.QuestionId, d => d.MapFrom(s => s.Subject))
                .ForMember(..)
                .ForMember(..);
```

However Automapper seems to not be able to do the mapping... What am I missing? Do I reeally have to use the `.ConvertUsing()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really reproduce the problem, but the following seems to work just as expected. AutoMapper should be able to handle collections with no special setup:

```
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceQuestionnaireSubmission, DestQuestionnaireSubmission>()
        .ForMember(d => d.ParticipantId, d => d.MapFrom(s => s.ParticipationId))
        .ForMember(d => d.SurveyVersionId, d => d.MapFrom(s => s.Survey.Version))
        .ForMember(d => d.RespondantAnswers, d => d.MapFrom(s => s.States));

    cfg.CreateMap<State, RespondantAnswer>()
        .ForMember(d => d.QuestionId, d => d.MapFrom(s => s.QuestionId));

    })
    .CreateMapper();

var source = new SourceQuestionnaireSubmission
{
    ParticipationId = 1,
    Survey = new Survey { Version = 10 },
    States = new []
    {
        new State { QuestionId = 100 },
        new State { QuestionId = 999 }
    }
};
        
var dest = mapper.Map<SourceQuestionnaireSubmission, DestQuestionnaireSubmission>(source);

Console.WriteLine("ParticipantId: {0}", dest.ParticipantId);
Console.WriteLine("SurveyVersionId: {0}", dest.SurveyVersionId);
Console.WriteLine("RespondantAnswers: {0}",
    string.Join(", ", dest.RespondantAnswers.Select(a => a.QuestionId)));

// Output:
// ParticipantId: 1
// SurveyVersionId: 10
// RespondantAnswers: 100, 999
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x9KcQ7) for a demonstration.

Comment: Thanks !!! I feel stupid, my inexperience with AutoMapper prevented me from reading further than : "AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException : Error mapping types." 

There was a conversion error between two property (trying to put value `d` in an `Int32`) which was making the conversion crashed. My setup works perfectly.